# Using functions from a C++ .DLL within Delphi

Tags: c++, dll, export, static-linking, freepascal

I am trying to access various functions from the 'Approximate nearest neighbor' ([ANN](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/)) library from within Delphi (actually, it is Lazarus/FreePascal, but that shouldn't matter much).

Here is the deceleration in C++:

```
#include <cstdlib>                      // C standard lib defs
#include <ANN/ANNx.h>                   // all ANN includes
#include <ANN/ANNperf.h>                // ANN performance 

using namespace std;                    // make std:: accessible
....
....
void annMaxPtsVisit(            // set limit on max. pts to visit in search
    int                 maxPts)         // the limit
{
    ANNmaxPtsVisited = maxPts;
}
```

And here is my attempt to access the `annMaxPtsVisit` function from within Lazarus (pretend its delphi if you don't know what Lazarus is):

```
unit unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls;
type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure annMaxPtsVisit(input:Integer); stdcall;
  private

    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}
{ TForm1 }
procedure TForm1.annMaxPtsVisit(input: Integer); stdcall; external 'ANN.dll' name 'annMaxPtsVisit';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
           annMaxPtsVisit(10);
end;

end.
```

The program compiles, but when I attempt to execute it I get an error message:

**"The procedure entry point annMaxPtsVisit could not be located in the dynamic link library ANN.dll"**

If anyone could help me out with this I would really appreciate it.

Here are the exports from the DLL:

```
class ANNsampStat ann_average_err   
class ANNsampStat ann_rank_err  
const ANNbd_tree::`vftable' 
const ANNbruteForce::`vftable'  
const ANNkd_tree::`vftable' 
const ANNpointSet::`vftable'    
double * * __cdecl annAllocPts(int,int) 
double * __cdecl annAllocPt(int,double) 
double * __cdecl annCopyPt(int,double *)    
double __cdecl annDist(int,double *,double *)   
protected: void __thiscall ANNkd_tree::SkeletonTree(int,int,int,double * *,int *)   
public: __thiscall ANNbd_tree::ANNbd_tree(class ANNbd_tree const &) 
public: __thiscall ANNbd_tree::ANNbd_tree(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)  
public: __thiscall ANNbd_tree::ANNbd_tree(double * *,int,int,int,enum ANNsplitRule,enum ANNshrinkRule)  
public: __thiscall ANNbd_tree::ANNbd_tree(int,int,int)  
public: __thiscall ANNbruteForce::ANNbruteForce(class ANNbruteForce const &)    
public: __thiscall ANNbruteForce::ANNbruteForce(double * *,int,int) 
public: __thiscall ANNkd_tree::ANNkd_tree(class ANNkd_tree const &) 
public: __thiscall ANNkd_tree::ANNkd_tree(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)  
public: __thiscall ANNkd_tree::ANNkd_tree(double * *,int,int,int,enum ANNsplitRule) 
public: __thiscall ANNkd_tree::ANNkd_tree(int,int,int)  
public: __thiscall ANNpointSet::ANNpointSet(class ANNpointSet const &)  
public: __thiscall ANNpointSet::ANNpointSet(void)   
public: __thiscall ANNsampStat::ANNsampStat(void)   
public: class ANNbd_tree & __thiscall ANNbd_tree::operator=(class ANNbd_tree const &)   
public: class ANNbruteForce & __thiscall ANNbruteForce::operator=(class ANNbruteForce const &)  
public: class ANNkd_tree & __thiscall ANNkd_tree::operator=(class ANNkd_tree const &)   
public: class ANNpointSet & __thiscall ANNpointSet::operator=(class ANNpointSet const &)    
public: class ANNsampStat & __thiscall ANNsampStat::operator=(class ANNsampStat const &)    
public: double __thiscall ANNsampStat::max(void)    
public: double __thiscall ANNsampStat::mean(void)   
public: double __thiscall ANNsampStat::min(void)    
public: double __thiscall ANNsampStat::stdDev(void) 
public: int __thiscall ANNsampStat::samples(void)   
public: virtual __thiscall ANNbd_tree::~ANNbd_tree(void)    
public: virtual __thiscall ANNbruteForce::~ANNbruteForce(void)  
public: virtual __thiscall ANNkd_tree::~ANNkd_tree(void)    
public: virtual __thiscall ANNpointSet::~ANNpointSet(void)  
public: virtual double * * __thiscall ANNbruteForce::thePoints(void)    
public: virtual double * * __thiscall ANNkd_tree::thePoints(void)   
public: virtual int __thiscall ANNbruteForce::annkFRSearch(double *,double,int,int *,double *,double)   
public: virtual int __thiscall ANNbruteForce::nPoints(void) 
public: virtual int __thiscall ANNbruteForce::theDim(void)  
public: virtual int __thiscall ANNkd_tree::annkFRSearch(double *,double,int,int *,double *,double)  
public: virtual int __thiscall ANNkd_tree::nPoints(void)    
public: virtual int __thiscall ANNkd_tree::theDim(void) 
public: virtual void __thiscall ANNbruteForce::annkSearch(double *,int,int *,double *,double)   
public: virtual void __thiscall ANNkd_tree::annkSearch(double *,int,int *,double *,double)  
public: virtual void __thiscall ANNkd_tree::Dump(enum ANNbool,class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)  
public: virtual void __thiscall ANNkd_tree::getStats(class ANNkdStats &)    
public: virtual void __thiscall ANNkd_tree::Print(enum ANNbool,class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &) 
public: void __thiscall ANNkd_tree::`default constructor closure'(void) 
public: void __thiscall ANNkd_tree::annkPriSearch(double *,int,int *,double *,double)   
public: void __thiscall ANNsampStat::operator+=(double) 
public: void __thiscall ANNsampStat::reset(void)    
void __cdecl annClose(void) 
void __cdecl annDeallocPt(double * &)   
void __cdecl annDeallocPts(double * * &)    
void __cdecl annMaxPtsVisit(int)    
void __cdecl annPrintStats(enum ANNbool)    
void __cdecl annResetCounts(void)   
void __cdecl annResetStats(int) 
void __cdecl annUpdateStats(void)
```

Comment: The code you post cannot be the code you actually have. The code you post doesn't compile. You are reporting a runtime error message.

Comment: Are you sure the name in the DLL is acutally `annMaxPtsVisit`? I find that really unlikely considering the code is C++ (it would even be unlikely for a lot of windows DLLs as they often use the `__stdcall` calling convention and are called `_func@4` and the like). Could you use a tool to dump the exports of the DLL for us?

Comment: @David Which are you talking about? The delphi code? Maybe it doesn't compile because its technically not actually delphi - its freepascal/lazarus.

Comment: @David Ok - I edited my initial question and added that info.

Comment: @Mike `procedure TForm1.annMaxPtsVisit .... external ....` can't be valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe importing by index works:

```
procedure annMaxPtsVisit(input: Integer); stdcall; external 'ANN.dll' index 39;
```

(That's the index gotten via [Dependecy Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/))

And you might have to change to `cdecl` calling convention, depending on how the DLL was built:

```
procedure annMaxPtsVisit(input: Integer); cdecl; external 'ANN.dll' index 39; // could work
```

**Edit**: Looks like `cdecl` is the right thing to do, looking at your added exports.

**Edit2**: Dependency walker shows also the decorated names, as @user786653 suspected. This also seems to work:

```
procedure annMaxPtsVisit(input: Integer); cdecl; external 'ANN.dll' Name '?annMaxPtsVisit@@YAXH@Z';
```

Looks ugly, though.

Comment: It is cdecl. From the export dump: `void __cdecl annMaxPtsVisit(int)` It probably just needs an underscore in front of the name instead of doing it by index (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks\(v=vs.80\).aspx))

Comment: Using `index 39` worked! Thanks a lot.... its kind of weird that it wouldn't work without it, isn't it?

Comment: I'm also used to using "nice" names.

Comment: Yup the decorated function works as well. Thanks a ton for the help :)

Comment: No problem. Also had to struggle with some C++ DLLs in the past ;)

Comment: Note that importing per index is really fragile (and by the mangled C++ name is really ugly). If you have control over building the source code I'd recommend exporting using `extern "C"` to get the name `_annMaxPtsVisit`. In general exporting C++ interfaces through DLLs is rather messy. But that was just a side note, glad it worked out :)

Comment: @user786653 Looking at the source code, it seems to use DLL_EXPORT. Would I just need to replace that with `extern "C"`?

Comment: @Mike Furlender: `DLL_EXPORT` is something specific to that program (it's probably `#define`d as `__declspec(dllexport)`) and it's never as simple just changing some little thing when we're talking about DLLs :). What I was refering to is what is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wf2w9f6x\(v=VS.80\).aspx). If that doesn't cover it I think you should probably start a new question.

Answer (score 3):

First of all declare `annMaxPtsVisit` as ordinary procedure, not a TForm1 method:

```
procedure annMaxPtsVisit(input: Integer); stdcall; external 'ANN.dll';
```

Comment: See my comment on @Heinrich's answer stdcall at least needs to be changed to cdecl